# Complex text parsing in Access

Tags: python, ms-access, vba

A year or two back, I became quite proficient using the data model in ArcGIS to mess with attribute tables. ArcGIS uses Access-type databases which enable the user to add, remove and modify fields. Within the ArcGIS interface I could create a new column, and run a script on this column using something called the "Field Calculator" using Python. The following algorithm for example took as input strings like "230 04th street" and convert them to "230 4th street". It also did some other replacement as were fit for the project.

```
def calc(f1,f2,f3):
#where f1 is address number, f2 is address name and f3 is address suffix
#Strip trailing and ending spaces from all fields 
    #Define list
    remove_list = ['01ST', '02ND', '03RD', '04TH', '05TH', '06TH', '07TH', '08TH', '09TH']

    #Homogenize single digit address names
    if f2 in remove_list:
        f2 = f2.replace('0','')
    else:
        f2 = f2

    f1 = str(f1).replace('.0','')
    #strip leading and trailing spaces
    f1 = f1.strip()
    f2 = f2.strip()
    f3 = f3.strip()     
    #adapt address number to string format

    #Concatenate full address name
    x = f1+' '+f2+' '+f3
    #Return Full address name
    return x
```

I want to have a similar sort of flexibility in Access. The closest thing to ArcGIS "Field Calculator" within Access is the "Expression Builder". This expression builder is ok for simple modifications but rather cumbersome to use for more complicated string parsing algorithms. Does anything in Access provide this sort of scripting for individual fields? Can we use VBA or other language inside the Expression Builder? Perhaps just SQL is the solution?

Comment: Your script fragment is completely doable in Visual Basic. VB is the scripting langage of Access. You don't use VB "inside" the expression builder, rather, you can work with the expression builder from VB. Can we have examples of your "more complicated strings" for a parsing algorithm?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - not to be a stickler, but you meant Visual Basic for Applications. VBA is the coding interface for MS Office, not VB, the general-purpose language. VB gurus would have a fit with this misnomer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-defined functions can be integrated in MS Access if you have the full UI .exe program. Simply script the function in a Module object and call it either in VBA or in SQL:

```
Public Function Calc(f1 As String, f2 As String, f3 As String) As String
    ' where f1 is address number, f2 is address name and f3 is address suffix '
    Dim remove_list() As Variant
    Dim r As Variant
    Dim x As String

    ' Define list '
    remove_list = Array("01ST", "02ND", "03RD", "04TH", "05TH", _
                        "06TH", "07TH", "08TH", "09TH")

    ' Homogenize single digit address names '
    For Each r In remove_list
        If f2 Like "*r*" Then
            f2 = Replace(f2, r, Right(r, 3))
        Else
            f2 = f2
        End If
    Next r

    f1 = Replace(f1, ".0", "")
    ' strip leading and trailing spaces '
    f1 = Trim(f1)
    f2 = Trim(f2)
    f3 = Trim(f3)

    ' Concatenate full address name '
    x = f1 & " " & f2 & " " & f3

    ' Return Full address name '
    Calc = x

End Function
```

**VBA**

```
Public Sub CleanAddress()
    Dim fullAddress As String
    Dim db As Database, rst As Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("TableName")

    If rst.RecordCount = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Do While Not rst.EOF

        fullAddress = Calc(rst!f1, rst!f2, rst!f3)
        rst.MoveNext

    Loop

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT t.*, Calc(t.f1, t.f2, t.f3) As fullAddress
FROM TableName t
```

And since function is not too complex, you can handle all in SQL with nested string functions:

**SQL**

```
SELECT t.*,
    Trim(t.f1, Replace(t.f1, '.0', '')) & 

    Replace(
        Replace(
            Replace(
                Replace(
                    Replace(
                        Replace(
                            Replace(
                                Replace(
                                    Replace(Trim(t.f2), '01ST', '1ST'), 
                                '02ND', '2ND'), 
                            '03RD', '3RD'),
                        '04TH', '4TH'),
                    '05TH', '5TH'),
               '06TH', '6TH'),
            '07TH', '7TH'),
        '08TH', '8TH'),
    '09TH', '9TH') &

    Trim(t.f3)  As FullAddress

FROM TableName As t
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... input strings like "230 04th street" and convert them to "230 4th
>   street"

That example can be implemented in Access with a custom VBA function which uses a regular expression.

Here is such a function tested in the Access Immediate window:

```vb
? Field_Calculator("230 04th street")
230 4th street
```

Note the pattern will not match text segments such as *"34th"*, *"045th"*, or *"04abc"*.  So those will be unaltered by the function:

```vb
? Field_Calculator("230 34th street")
230 34th street
? Field_Calculator("230 045th street")
230 045th street
? Field_Calculator("230 04abc street")
230 04abc street
```

This is the function, written to use late binding:

```vb
Public Function Field_Calculator(ByVal pInput As String) As String
    Const cstrPattern As String = "\b(0)(\d\w{2})\b"
    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With objRegExp
        .Pattern = cstrPattern
        .IgnoreCase = True
        Field_Calculator = .Replace(pInput, "$2")
    End With
End Function
```

If you prefer early binding, set a reference to *"Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions"* and make these changes:

```vb
'Dim objRegExp As Object
'Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim objRegExp As RegExp
Set objRegExp = New RegExp
```

The function could be called from another VBA procedure.  It could also be used in Access SQL when run from within an Access session:

```sql
UPDATE YourTable
SET [street_address] = Field_Calculator([street_address]);
```

However a query which uses a custom VBA function can not be run from outside an Access session.